# как передать переменную с помощью header

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование, сессия

Суть в том, что есть код:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['email']=$email;
print("Выполнен вход. Your Email: ".$email." Your password: ".$password);
header("Location:str.php");
```

Надо передать переменную $email на str.php, как видно сессия открывается, на странице str.php эта переменная пытается вывестись с помощью echo $_SESSION['email], но выводится пустота.

Comment: покажите код str.php. подозреваю что в нём забыли стартануть сессию.

Comment: Сделайте  `echo (bool)session_start();` - так вы увидите запускается ли сессия вообще, 1 - если да, 0 - если нет. Возможно настроили конфиг не правильно, или какие либо другие причины. Да и вообще желательно включить вывод ошибок и об ошибках сообщать сюда.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нельзя выводить на экран `print()` перед функцией `header()`.

по идее должно показать ошибку такого типа: `(Cannot modify header information)`
и в файле "str.php" у тебя тоже должна стартовать сессия  `session_start();`.

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо удалить `print()`

Запись в Header возможна если буфер чист, нельзя выводить никаких символов до функции `header()`